# Create image of, "specific page" of postscript file using ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript, postscript, image-conversion

Please someone help me with ghostscript....

I want to create image of a particular page postscript file using ghostscript. I will specify the page number or something like that will get the respective image as output.

Is this possible with ghostscript?

Comment: Welcome to SO !!! It would help you to get answer faster if you tell what you have tried so far.

Comment: Script1.--------gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage="1" -dLastPage="1" -sOutputFile=outputFilePath.gif -dJPEGQ=100 -r300 -q inputFilePath.pdf -c quit 

Script2.--------gs -dUseCIEColor -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage="1" -dLastPage="1" -sOutputFile=outputfile.gif  -dJPEGQ=100 -r300 -q inputFile.ps -c quit; 

We are using ghostscript for creating images from pdf and ps files.

In case of pdf ghostscript creates image of a particular page in case of miltipage pdf as in in script 1.

Comment: Where as when we create image from ps file then page wise image is not created and it always create all pages images.

Someone please help whether I am missing something, whether it is possible by ghostscript or not.

Answer (score 1):

In current versions of Ghostscript you have two choices:

1) Render every page to an image file, use the '%d' file name format so that you know which page you want, delete the others.

2) PostScript is a programming language. Write a customer EndPage procedure which returns true when the page is the one you want, and false for all others.

In a yet to be released version of Ghostscript, the FirstPage and LastPage paramters could be used to do this.

Comment: KenS I have added comment briefing my scenario, please help also can you elaborate how to do it in postscript...

Comment: The 9.18 release is imminent, just wait for that and then use -dFirstPage and -dLastPage. You can even try out the release candidate. You can't use these parameters with any earlier version, except when the input is **PDF**.