# someone help me with GhostScript

Tags: ghostscript

Script1.--------gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage="1" -dLastPage="1" -sOutputFile=outputFilePath.gif -dJPEGQ=100 -r300 -q inputFilePath.pdf -c quit

Script2.--------gs -dUseCIEColor -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage="1" -dLastPage="1" -sOutputFile=outputfile.gif  -dJPEGQ=100 -r300 -q inputFile.ps -c quit;

We are using ghostscript for creating images from pdf and ps files.

In case of pdf ghostscript creates image of a particular page in case of miltipage pdf as in in script 1.

Where as when we create image from ps file then page wise image is not created and it always create all pages images.

Someone please help whether I am missing something, whether it is possible by ghostscript or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create image of, "specific page" of postscript file using ghostscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476903/create-image-of-specific-page-of-postscript-file-using-ghostscript)

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate of your previous question, the answer is the same. In versions prior to 9.18 the -dFirstPage and -dLastPage parameters **only** apply to PDF input.

You either need to write a custom EndPage procedure (see the 3rd Edition PostScript Language Reference Manual) or use version 9.18 (or later) of Ghostscript.